# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when trying to print error from Swift 4 do-try-catch, skipping specified catch conditions

Tags: swift, try-catch

I'm trying to catch my custom Error, but for some reason my catch statements where I name the error that I know is being thrown, it skips those, goes to the default catch, and then gives me a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION  (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) when I try to do `print("Unexpected error \(error)")`

Here's some abbreviated code:

This is the error that I have declared in my file that houses the class that I'm calling the method on (the class is called CC8DB):

```
public enum CC8RSVPError: Error {
    case noEventOnDate
    case invalidRSVPValue
}
```

I have a method declared as:

```
public func rsvpForEvent(_ inEventDate:Date?, forUserID inUserID:String, withValue inRSVPValue:String) throws -> CC8RSVPStatus
```

In another class were I'm calling this method, I have this:

```
do {
    let rsvpResponse = try self.cc8DB.rsvpForEvent(inRSVPDate, forUserID: String(inMessage.author.id.rawValue), withValue: inRSVPValue);
    ...(other code to do when this doesn't fail)...
} catch CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPValue {
    ...(Report specific error to user)...
} catch CC8RSVPError.noEventOnDate {
    ...(Report specific error to user)...
} catch {
    ...(Report general error to user)...
    print("Error doing RSVP: \(error)");
}
```

And finally, in the CC8DB.rsvpForEvent() method, I'm triggering an error that does this:

```
throw CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPValue;
```

The germane part of this method is:

```
public func rsvpForEvent(_ inEventDate:Date?, forUserID inUserID:String, withValue inRSVPValue:String) throws -> CC8RSVPStatus
    {
        var retStatus = CC8RSVPStatus(eventDate: nil, previousRSVP: "", newRSVP: "");
        var upperRSVPValue:String = inRSVPValue.uppercased();
        if (["YES", "MAYBE", "NO"].contains(upperRSVPValue)) {
            //...(Code to do things when the info is correct)...
        } else {
            throw CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPValue;
        }

        return retStatus;
    }
```

For my test case where I'm seeing this, the inRSVPValue is "bla", to test what happens when a user doesn't enter a valid status value.

What I'm seeing is that rather than going into the `catch` that's specific for the `CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPValue` case, it's going down to the general `catch`. In addition, I'm getting the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on the line where I try and print the `error` value.
I've stepped through it to verify that I am indeed hitting the `throw` line that I think I am, and I can see in the debugger that the value of `error` is `CC8DB.CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPValue`, but even if I try to do `po error` from the lldb command, I get the same exception error.

Has anyone seen this or know what I could have done to make do-try-catch not work right?

Comment: Can you please update the question with rsvpForEvent method definition?

Comment: Updated the question (although as I mentioned, I've already verified that it's throwing the CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPError in the `else` block by stepping through the execution).

Comment: So I backed off and tried something simpler: defining another `Error` enum in the same .swift file as I'm running things in, and setting up a call that always throws, so I could try the catch there. In that case, it worked as expected. Is there something about scoping with `throw` statements, since the method that throws in my original question is in a different class, defined in a different .swift file, as where I'm doing the `catch`? It seems like if it compiles, it should work, but the behavior seems to contradict that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I realized that somewhere along the way, some build setting got set so that I was statically linking into the binary (this is a command-line tool, a bot for Discord to be specific).
I saw some warnings about some of the Swift runtime libs being found in both the binary and the XCode developer runtime area, and realized that it might be that the error object was being used both in my CC8DB module in the binary and in the built-modules folder (or something to that effect).
I need to statically link for when I actually deploy the bot to where it's going to run, so I must have turned something on that won't turn off (I deleted the extra flags that I thought turned that on, but that wasn't fixing it).

Basically, I recreated my .xcodeproj file with `swift package generate-xcodeproj` to clear out whatever I broke, and now it works as expected.

Thanks to everyone who looked at this and offered help (especially @gmogames for his time and help). I'm sure it helped lead me down the path of figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a constant named error inside your catch statement and inside the catch block read the constant and figure out what to do with it.

do something like:

```
} catch let error {
    switch error {
        case CC8RSVPError.noEventOnDate:
        // code
        case CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPValue:
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to contradict Apple's documentation on error handling (in the section "Handling Errors Using Do-Catch"). https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: @TorgoKong did you try to print/breakpoint debug and see the content of error to see if it's matching to your error enum?

Comment: Yes. I actually mentioned that in the original post at the bottom. The local variable list shows the `error` variable as CC8DB.CC8RSVPError.invalidRSVPValue, but it appears to ignore that `catch` and go right down to the catch-all one. If I right-click it and do "Print Description" or if I do `po error` at the lldb command, I get the same EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, so in addition to not going where it seems like it should go, I can't even print out what it is.

Comment: @TorgoKong sorry what I meant is, use the piece of code I gave as an example (with assigning a let error constant in catch) and try to print error there and see the type/content if matches yours.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Using that form, I basically get the same thing. It skips matching any of the CC8RSVPError enums, and drops to the default: case, where I get the same EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on a line that has `print("I dunno. \(error)")` I added a comment to my original post, wondering if it has something to do with the error enum being declared in another .swift file.